# way to open at AHK the first file at a folder

Tags: directory, autohotkey

If I want to open the first pic (alphabetic order) of a folder of all .jpg it is not working

```
Run ...\*.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
; First of all make sure that such a file exists in the folder specified
If FileExist("D:\MyFolder\*.jpg")
{
    ; loop through those files  
    Loop, Files, D:\MyFolder\*.jpg
    {
        If (A_Index = 1) ; as soon as the first file (in alphanumeric order) is retrievend
            Run %A_LoopFileFullPath% ; run this file
                break ; and terminate the loop
    }
}
else
    MsgBox, "D:\MyFolder" doesn't contain any jpg-files
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileExist.htm